# Does Azure EventGrid have defined outbound IP address

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

My company supports a product that leverages Azure EventGrid to send notifications through a webhook.

One of our customers (sensibly) is wanting to limit the range of IP addresses that they can receive notifications through.

Does EventGrid have a defined address or range of addresses that can be designated?

Answer (score 2):

EventGrid has a [Event Domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains) feature to control who can receive events. That's likely to be the closest to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to make sure the IPs for eventgrid are open, IPs are listed in the Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags doc available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519 .  Open it in VSCode then search for EventGrid.

```
{
  "name": "AzureEventGrid",
  "id": "AzureEventGrid",
  "properties": {
    "changeNumber": 1,
    "region": "",
    "platform": "Azure",
    "systemService": "AzureEventGrid",
    "addressPrefixes": [
      "13.86.56.32/27",
      "13.86.56.160/27",
      "52.149.23.160/27",
      "52.149.48.80/28",
      "52.149.48.96/27",
      "52.149.248.0/28",
      "52.149.248.64/27",
      "52.149.248.96/28",
      "52.167.21.160/27",
      "52.167.21.208/28",
      "52.167.21.224/28",
      "52.185.212.176/28",
      "52.185.212.192/28",
      "52.255.80.16/28",
      "52.255.82.160/28"
    ]
  }
```